# AS3 Bad performance at edges of large stage

Tags: performance, actionscript-3

Using a large stage size of 3840 x 2160, I see performance issues when animating small sprites towards the edges of the stage.

I can add hundreds of these to the stage with no problem, but if any are near the edges, problems occur. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

**Update:**

`sprite.cacheAsBitmap = true` was causing the problem for me. Setting to `false` fixed the issue.

Comment: I've seen this asked before. Do you have any custom functions for those near edge? Maybe it's a Adobe issue.

Comment: nope just a straight up expanding pulse - increasing radius, decreasing alpha, graphics.clear(), and redraw on each frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably has to do with how flash player renders the screen. It redraws everything in between the four outermost to-be-redrawn coordinates.
(most left, most right, most up, most down)

Meaning that if you've got only two pixels at coordinate 1600,1000 and one at 1800,1200 that have changed in between frames, then only an area of 200x200 pixels is redrawn. If however you have a pixel at 10,10 and one at 3830,2150 that need to be redrawn, then an area of 3820x2140 pixels needs to be rerendered. That's mucho pixels. (8.174.800)

This is true even if nothing else has changed in between those four outermost pixels.

Comment: Yep, I'd suggest using the "show redraw regions" context menu option to see what's going on.

Comment: Enabled with: `flash.profiler.showRedrawRegions(true)` and could see the redraw regions where ok - until the sprite exceeded the bounds of the stage, at which point the redraw expanded to the whole stage

Comment: the problem was `cacheAsBitmap = true` setting to false fixed the problem! cheers.